# Error when importing RegularGridInterpolator from scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, scipy

I have a problem when trying to run a code for a course at the university. The main file BASEchange.py tries to import 2 modules called "NODE" and "MESHMODEL". "MESHMODEL", in turn, imports RegularGridInterpolator from scipy.interpolate .

When I run the program in the mac terminal, using "python BASEchange.py -h", I get the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name RegularGridInterpolator

I have scipy intalled via pip.

Here are the first lines form meshModel.py:

```
import sys, os, platform, subprocess, stat, re, abc, math, linecache, shutil
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix, lil_matrix, tril, find
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import reverse_cuthill_mckee
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the `scipy` version?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong version of scipy. Note that `RegularGridInterpolator` are only supported from `version 0.14.`

Do the following.

upgrade your pip

- for Python 3:

  `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
- for Python 2:

  `python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Then Follow the commands from [here](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) to install scipy:

`python -m pip install --user scipy`

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! I will try it out this evening and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. This is what the terminal spits out: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (0.13.0b1)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer `RegularGridInterpolator` is only supported in `Version 0.14` and your error confirms that you have `o.13.ob1`.You need to ideally use python3 as this will have up to date pip. Can you try installing python3 and follow the commands to install Scipy. Install latest python from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: I already have python 3, and this problem is now solved. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great. You may also want to add an answer on how you solved it so that others with the same/similar problem can benefit from it.

Comment: As you have already said, I had to use Python3. Python 2.7 does not update to a version of RegGridInt newer than 0.13.0b1. The current difficulty will now be to figure out how to update the code to py3, since it had been written to run with version 2.7. The reason I asked the question in the first place was that I had expected there to be some way to make the program run with python 2.7